# Determining the type of convergence of a series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, factorial

The specific homework problem is $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots2n}{n!}$.  It is problem #29 from the section 11.6 exercises (pg. 737) from *Single Variable Calculus: Early Transcendentals - 4th Edition* by James Stewart.  What we have to do is determine the type of convergence that occurs, i.e. absolute convergence, conditional convergence, or divergence.  I understand that the test that I will have to do to solve this problem will probably be the ratio test.  The problem that I am having in doing this is identifying the expression in the numerator of the problem.  I think it is a factorial of some sorts, where it starts at $2n$ and then decreases by $2$ every single time instead of $1$.  I do not know how to write this expression in the form of some sort of function.  So my question is: is there any way to write a factorial that decreases by $2$ instead of $1$ or do I just have the wrong expression entirely for the numerator.

EDIT:
Solution:
To show that I did not just blatantly copy the answer provided by savick01, I will explain how s/he got it.  What happened is that, after having pulled out a $2$ from each value in the expression, it became of the form $2(1)\cdot2(2)\cdot2(3)\cdots2(n)$.  Further simplification of this, after considering the fact that the values in the parenthesis form the factorial and that there are $n$ factors in a factorial, results in $2^n\cdot n!$.

Comment: Isn't it just $n! \cdot 2^n$ ?

Comment: It is also denoted by $(2n)!!$, which is defined also for odd $m$: $m!! = m \cdot (m-2) \cdot \ldots \cdot 1$.

Comment: @savick01 Thank you very much, I didn't realize that I could factor things out of a factorial.

Comment: The standard "sum" for the divergent series is $-1$.

Comment: I find the "$!!$" notation obnoxious because it looks like an iterated factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll see good things happen if you factor out 2s.  Does this help answer your question?